# Library for numerical Integration of a function over a tetrahedron (3D)

Tags: python, math, numerical-integration, finite-element-analysis

I am looking for å python library that has a function to solve 3D integrals over a tetrahedron. I would like to be able to input four points on the form (x, y, z) and a function f(x, y, z) where f is a polynomial function.

Have only found functions that accepts integration boundaries that go from function to function, but I need an integration tool that accepts points.

Comment: I've never used scipy for this but it probably has something useful. What kind of function is this though? Depending on the function, computing the integral might be easy or hard.

Comment: There is [scipy.integrate.tplquad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html#scipy.integrate.tplquad). It looks like it will require a (simple?) change of variables to use properly.

Comment: Gaussian quadrature over a unit tetrahedron is common in finite element analysis.  You'd just need a transformation from local to global coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [quadpy library](https://github.com/sigma-py/quadpy#tetrahedron-t3) to integrate a function over a tetrahedron.

But for a polynomial function `f`, it is possible to calculate the exact value of the integral of `f` over a tetrahedron (more generally over a simplex in any dimension). This method is implemented in the R package **SimplicialCubature**. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.06736.pdf) provides another method; I implemented it in Python: [gist](https://gist.github.com/stla/1176c313a9bf54de867c065f5713a973).

---

## EDIT

I made a [package](https://github.com/stla/PySimplicialCubature) now.